# Sliding pages like in the Launchpad (Mac) or the IPhone's main menu

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, slide, uisegmentedcontrol

I got an ios app, where i want show content on some pages, like in the Launchpad (Mac) or  the IPhone's main menu.

I know that white circles is - `UISegmentedControl`. But it can only changes some values. But what about sliding? May be i can realize Launchpad's pages behavior with `UIScrollView`? But how? I cant find some tutorials, please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this [Tutorial](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/). It will solve your problem.

Comment: thnx. i will try it right now. if all is ok, i will accpet your answer =)